# <td> specific formatting will change background color but not border color

Tags: html, css, dom, html-table

this is driving me up the wall.

I have a loop that spits a table back from php into my html page. grabs the last 30 'messages' posted into a DB Table along with some other things.  I have a dynamic color coding based on what the user sets as their message background color.  Works fine.  When logged in, I want to show a different border color on that user's messages.  i.e. my messages have different border color when I am logged in. It works if i use my if statement to change the background color, but not the border color.

This Works and changes the background color:

```
$bgcol = 'bgcolor="#ecb3ff">'
if($uid == $userid){ $bgcol = 'bgcolor="white">';}
echo "<tr><td width='66%' " . $bgcol . $msg . "</td></tr>";
```

This Doesn't Work:

```
$bgcol = 'bgcolor="#ecb3ff">'
if($uid == $userid){ $bgcol = 'borderColor="black" ' . $bgcol;}
echo "<tr><td width='66%' " . $bgcol . $msg . "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using inline style like this :

```
$bgcol = 'background-color:#ecb3ff;'
if($uid == $userid){ $bgcol = 'border-color:black; '. $bgcol;}
echo "<tr><td width='66%' style='". $bgcol ."'>". $msg ."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: I tried that as well to no avail.  I even tried changing the font-color, etc. some other attributes just to test.  It'll only change the bgcolor for me.  but the widths I hard coded into the last line still work

Comment: I have bottom border across each row.  It even will change the bgcolor for that rows that fir the if statement criteria and skip the other attribute. i..

Comment: if($usertype == "2"){$bgcol = 'outline="2px solid white" '. 'bgcolor="white">';}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a class eventually ?

```
$class = '';
if($uid == $userid){ $class = 'bg1';}
echo "<tr><td width='66%' class='". $class ."'>". $msg ."</td></tr>";
```

CSS

```
td {
  background-color: #ecb3ff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

td.bg1 {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try as well!  The reason I was switching the background color individually is that in one mode, the users set their background color, and that is how it shows up in the stream of messages.  In another mode, users can pull only messages from one or multiple 'tags', and if it's multiple, the messages get color coded by tag to make it easier to differentiate.

Comment: But I could also do the same thing with classes as well.  Leave well enough alone with the bgcolor and try to change classes to get the border.  I'll follow up when I give it a whirl later.  Thanks!